# Datepicker Twitter bootstrap

Tags: datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added Bootstrap datepicker to my code by calling js like below:

```
$("#sampleid").datepicker();
```

But, the date color is white and it is not displaying in my white background. I want the date color to be black.

In datepicker css, in which class/id I want to change??? Even I changes some color in that also not working..

Comment: Maybe the color is inherited from another class. Try to inspect your element using chrome/firefox and F12 to open the developer panel (or right-click on the object, Inspect Element). There's a panel that tells you everything about CSS.

Comment: `I added Bootstrap datepicker` : which one ?

Comment: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: The default color from DatePicker is black: http://bootply.com/87089 -- You must have some custom CSS that is overriding it. Post your code or recreate it with Bootply.